# HTML SideNav Icons with negative position and not working collapse button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, display

I have two problems with my page.

First:
I have 3 hover-able buttons on right side of my page. They should work like [these buttons](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sidenav_buttons.asp), but on my page you can scroll to see their position "outside" of the page. I guess there is problem with display, but I don't know how to make it right. Does someone know how to fix this?

Second: 
When you zoom enough (bellow max-width: 992px) my navbar will move to sideNav and there should be collapse button "Přihlásit se", which should activate collapse from bootstrap and show the form, but that doesn't work too... I don't know why. :/

[There is a page!](http://zoo.luppix.net/)

Comment: post your code here, edit your question and add it

Comment: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gcx50fd/) is here, sorry for late respond

Answer (score 0):

about buttons there is many ways how you can achieve such behaviour, but based on your current markup with quick fixes, you should look into adding `overflow: hidden` to the container, for example `body` in your case and move buttons block(`.SideIconNav`) to `absolute` position, `.main` to `relative` and don't forget about `z-indexe's`

about form - you add `event.stopPropagation();` on `#mySidenav` which canceled click event before it fired on the button

Comment: Sorry for the late respond. Could you please show me how to fix this exactly... I tried to do that but it didn't worked...